# How do I made the Unity Input System work with multiple operating systems

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game that requires controller support and I am unsing the old input system (I have been working with the old input system and cannot update it easily). I am making the game on MacOS at home and on Windows in college. When I use MacOS, the controller input is different then on both operating systems.
For example: On Windows, the select button is "joystick button 7"
And on MacOS, the start button is "joystick button 11".

Overall, how do I make them both use a single joystick button?

Comment: Have you considered conditional compiles?

Answer (score 0):

You can remap it in the player settings (so you can rename both to 7 for example)
Or you can use #if and #else (the # means only visual studio or your code editor will check the platform BEFORE building instead of checking everytime the app is run which would be completely useless since your patform cant change on the same device) with Application.platform to check for the current operating system.